# Spring test: How to default configuration to @AnnotationDriven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Currently my class looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {DemographicAttributesManager.class})
public class DemographicAttributesManagerTest {

    @Autowired
    private DemographicAttributesManager demographicAttributesManager;

    @Test
    public void testGetGenders() throws Exception {
        final Map<Integer, String> genders = demographicAttributesManager.getGenders();
        assertEquals(3, genders.size());
    }
}
```

**What I don't like?**

1. In every Test class I have to include

> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Is there a way to default it? so that every test runs with that class?

1. I have to type

> @ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
>   classes = {DemographicAttributesManager.class})
>   telling which classes to include and that it is annotation driven test.

Is there a way to set default to `package` scanning for classes and default that I do not have to put `AnnotationConfigContextLoader`?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In every Test class I have to include `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
>
> Is there a way to default it? so that every test runs with that class?

No, there is no way to change the default `Runner` for JUnit. JUnit defines the default `Runner` as `org.junit.runners.JUnit4`. So if you want to use a different runner (e.g., `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`), you have to declare it explicitly. That's simply how JUnit works.

However, as someone else pointed out, the `@RunWith` annotation is inherited. So you can declare it on a base test class within your project that other test classes extend.

> I have to type `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {DemographicAttributesManager.class})` telling which classes to include and that it is annotation driven test.

You do *not* need to explicitly declare `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` as the loader. Whenever you declare the `classes` attribute of `@ContextConfiguration`, Spring automatically uses the `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` for you. The same is true if you a declare static inner `@Configuration` class, thereby making use of the default detection mechanism.

This is all well documented in the corresponding Javadoc as well as in the [*Testing* chapter of the Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework).

> Is there a way to set default to package scanning for classes and default that I do not have to put AnnotationConfigContextLoader?

Regarding `AnnotationConfigContextLoader`, see above.

Regarding package scanning, no, there is no explicit support for package scanning when using `@ContextConfiguration` on its own; however, it is certainly possible to configure component scanning for a given package using a static inner `@Configuration` class that is annotated with `@ComponentScan`. Naturally, you could also declare that configuration in the same base test class that is annotated with `@RunWith`.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: Awesome, That helps a lot Sam! I will try to include this in my codebase so that I write less ;)

Comment: Great! Maybe you would consider "accepting" my answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

@RunWith and @ContextConfiguration(loader=...) can be inherited from a base test class.
I don't know how to avoid @ContextConfiguration(classes=...) per test class.
But I don't think that getting rid of it is a very useful feature: I prefer to have true unit tests with mockito and without @RunWith(spring) and to have true integration tests that would load the whole app context (which will be cached by spring among all the tests).